# Not ending conversations in the reading end

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-broker

What happens if the RECEIVE end point do not end conversations when it get the END DIALOG message?

Will it eventually slow down SqlServer as it has to keep track of a lot of conversations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each conversation has a lifetime timer. If you did not specify the lifetime at [`BEGIN DIALOG`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187377.aspx) time then they get the default lifetime of ~68 years (2147483647 seconds). Unfinished endpoints have to be kept around for the entire lifetime. This consumes rows in [`sys.conversation_endpoints`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176082.aspx) so eventually your disk will fill up. Not only this, but also each active conversation endpoint requires memory (may be backed up by tempdb) and at database startup all conversations have to be scanned to determine any pending action (timer, lifetime).

All in all there simply is no reason no to issue your side of `END DIALOG`.